# WPF: How to enable a Command?

Tags: c#, wpf

I don't know why the Add item in my context menu is only enabled when there is an item selected in the ListView. Does anybody knows why?

Here's my XAML code

```
    <Window x:Class="Vokabular1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="grid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ListView Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,10" Name="listView" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView />
                </ListView.View>
                <ListView.CommandBindings>
                    <CommandBinding Command="New" 
                        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" 
                        CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
                </ListView.CommandBindings>
                <ListView.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Name="Add" Header="_Add"    Command="New" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="Delete" IsEnabled="True" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ListViewItem />  
            </ListView>            
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The methods for the window are:

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ok");
}

private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focus is required for the `CommandBinding.CanExecute` to be called. Since selecting an item in the `ListView` forces the focus to shift to the `ListView`; the evaluation can occur.

If you were to place `listView.Focus();` within your `Window` constructor you would note that `CommandBinding.CanExecute` is now called as expected and therefore enabled without an item being contained or selected within the `ListView`.

Moving the binding to the `Window` will still require the focus to get set within the `Window`; either via an explicit call within the constructor or by another means; ex... selecting an item in the `ListView` or other control within the `Window` which can receive focus.