# How to enable paste using CTRL+V in empty listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-3.0

I have an empty listbox which I would like to allow the user to paste items into. Currently I make sure the listbox has focus (as per [WPF: How to enable a Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143060/wpf-how-to-enable-a-command)) when the user clicks on it. Then if they right-click the context menu which contains the Paste command will be enabled and can be clicked which is excellent. However if instead of right-clicking the user presses CTRL+V on the keyboard the Paste command does not execute.

So far I can't figure out how to make this work. If the listbox has items in it and one of them is selected everything works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Add your own [CommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx) for the Paste-Command to the ListBox.

```
m_yourlistBoxReference.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste,YourExecutedHandler,YourCanExecuteHandler));
```

However, such as you already wrote, you have to ensure that the ListBox is focused, otherwise the `CommandBinding` will not execute. To ensure this, you can register to the PreviewMouseDown-event and focus the ListBox if not already `IsFocused` is true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a WPF expert; however, in WinForms the easiest way is to add a context menu with the short-cut keys for Cut, Copy, Paste, etc.  Then you don't have to do anything but implement the context menu click.