# CommandTarget with nested controls

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a custom WPF control that inherits from `ListView`. Each `ListViewItem` in this control can contain other such controls, and this can continue ad infinitum.

The custom `ListView` subclass has three `CommandBinding`s - Cut, Copy and Paste, as well as a `ContextMenu` that issues each of these commands. All work as expected on the top level - I can Cut, Copy, and Paste. However, if I right-click one of the nested `ListView`-descendant controls and select Paste (though the other two work identically), one of the following happens:

if the control has no selected `ListViewItem`s, the `CommandExecuted` event fires with the top `ListView` as `CommandTarget`.
if the control has a selected `ListViewItem`, everything works fine.

Is this a known issue? Are there any (decent) workarounds? Thanks.

**EDIT** As requested, here's an example:

Custom `ListView` subclass:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy,
            CopyCommand_Executed, CopyCutCommand_CanExecute));
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste,
            PasteCommand_Executed, PasteCommand_CanExecute));
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Ivory);
    }

    MyListItem Binding 
    { 
        get { return this.DataContext as MyListItem; } 
    }

    private void CopyCutCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled)
            return;

        e.CanExecute = (this.SelectedItems.Count > 0);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void CopyCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled)
            return;

        if (this.SelectedItems.Count < 0)
            return; // Nothing selected

        List<MyListItem> items = new List<MyListItem>();
        foreach (MyListItem str in this.SelectedItems)
            items.Add(str);

        Clipboard.SetData("Stuff", items);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void PasteCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled)
            return;

        e.CanExecute = Clipboard.ContainsData("Stuff");
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void PasteCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Handled)
            return;

        MyListView lv = this;

        List<MyListItem> strings = Clipboard.GetData("Stuff") as List<MyListItem>;
        if (strings == null)
            return;

        foreach (MyListItem s in strings)
            this.Binding.Items.Add(s);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Simple `ListViewItem` binding class:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyListItem
{
    public MyListItem() { this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MyListItem>(); }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

XAML for `MyControl` (no code-behind), representation of each `ListViewItem`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestNestedListView.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNestedListView">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption}" />
            <local:MyListView Padding="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`MainWindow` XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestNestedListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestNestedListView"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyListItem}">
            <local:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <local:MyListView x:Name="lv" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
        <local:MyListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="Paste" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </local:MyListView.ContextMenu>
    </local:MyListView>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow` code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyListItem root = new MyListItem();

        MyListItem item = new MyListItem() { Caption = "Item 1" };
        item.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { Caption = "Subitem 1.1" });
        root.Items.Add(item);
        root.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { Caption = "Item 2" });
        root.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { Caption = "Item 3" });
        root.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { Caption = "Item 4" });

        item = new MyListItem() { Caption = "Item 5" };
        item.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { Caption = "Subitem 5.1" });
        item.Items.Add(new MyListItem() { Caption = "Subitem 5.2" });

        root.Items.Add(item);

        lv.DataContext = root;
    }
}
```

To see this in action, right-click and Copy any item. Then right-click the rectangle (it's the `ListView`) under "Item 2" and click Paste. Note that the new item will be pasted as the last item in the top level. Right-click the rectangle under "Subitem 1.1", and note that the item is pasted as the child of "Item 1", not "Subitem 1.1".

Comment: post some code that reproduces this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143060/wpf-how-to-enable-a-command) list view has to have focus to handle commands properly. I've observed this flaw by adding an empty list view of your type to form and a text box. Then when I focus text box and have in clipboard some text paste command is active even on your list view none of CanExecute methods is fired and selecting paste command will paste to text box. This indeed looks like a bug in wpf, I found few articles that suggests it's known but I didn't find a ticket for it.

[Disabled ContextMenus in WPF bug](http://www.trentfguidry.net/post/2009/06/14/Disabled-ContextMenus-WPF.aspx)

[Why is my ContextMenu item disabled?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7bd75a7c-eab4-4f3a-967b-94a9534a7455/)

**Edit**

As a workaround for your scenario simply add:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Func<bool>(Focus));
}
```

To your `MyListView` class.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, and the workaround. I'll try it out, and 'accept' your answer once I can confirm.